# lightbox.js html5 video not playing video. what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, lightbox

i'm trying to get the example on this page working specifically because my video files are stored on my web server.

https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/demos/html5-videos.html

this is my html file. I followed the instructions on the lightbox github page but I must have missed something because the videos don't play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightgallery.css">
<link href="css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Hidden video div -->
    <div style="display:none;" id="video1">
        <video class="lg-video-object lg-html5 video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none">
            <source src="archive/devon_rayford/20200501.tom_hanks_gone.Q_dx99JcxT8.mp4" type="video/mp4">
             Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="video2">
        <video class="lg-video-object lg-html5 video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none">
            <source src="archive/devon_rayford/20200501.Tom_Hanks_is_really_gone.Hrx1YtkpfPY.mp4" type="video/mp4">
             Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>

    <!-- data-src should not be provided when you use html5 videos -->
    <ul id="video-gallery">
      <li data-poster="archive/devon_rayford/thumbnails/20200501.tom_hanks_gone.Q_dx99JcxT8.jpg" data-sub-html="video caption1" data-html="#video1" >
          <img src="archive/devon_rayford/thumbnails/20200501.tom_hanks_gone.Q_dx99JcxT8.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-poster="archive/devon_rayford/thumbnails/20200501.Tom_Hanks_is_really_gone.Hrx1YtkpfPY.jpg" data-sub-html="video caption2" data-html="#video2" >
          <img src="archive/devon_rayford/thumbnails/20200501.Tom_Hanks_is_really_gone.Hrx1YtkpfPY.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
<!-- Include lg-video -->
<script src="js/lg-video.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include other lightgallery plugins (Optional) -->
<script src="js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>

<script>
lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery')); 
lightGallery(document.getElementById('video-gallery'), 
{
    videojs: true
});

lightGallery(document.getElementById('html5-videos')); 

$('#html5-videos').lightGallery();
$('#video-gallery').lightGallery({ 
    videojs: true
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the minify version of the lightgallery.min.js having some unknown errors. I tried using the real version and it works well.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery.js@1.1.3/dist/js/lightgallery.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-video.js/master/dist/lg-video.js"></script>
```

I haven't tried the jQuery version yet.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/arbiyanto/6e2L371m/13/)